# What are the limitations for hash functions with std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map

I am using std::unordered_map to represent data in a 3Dimensional  spatial arrangement. My hashing function is:

```
unsigned int x,y,z;
unsigned int a =1000;
unsigned int b = 1000*a;
unsigned int Hash = x + a*y + b*z;
```

Which should allow for up to 1000 units of x, 1000 units of y, before there are any collisions. 
My question is, are there any limits to the collision-free space of my hash function? or can I set a and b to be large numbers, noting that this would easily exceed the memory of my system if it was all allocated?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some background on the operation of hashtables:

Hashtables don't allocate enough buckets to hold the *entire* space of the hash function.  That would indeed be wasteful (and probably also impossible).  They allocate a certain number of buckets (say 16) and then store each pair in the bucket that the key hashes to *modulo the number of buckets.*

The number of buckets is increased when the map reaches a certain threshold (usually 75-85%) of occupied buckets.  This forces a rehash of all of the keys so they can be applied to a new modulo.

So if your hash function returns 50 for a particular key, and the hashtable has 16 buckets, the pair for that key is stored in bucket (50 mod 16) = 2.

If the number of buckets is later increased to 32, the pair gets moved to the bucket (50 mod 32) = 18.

> can I set a and b to be large numbers

Absolutely, because the hash modulo the number of allocated buckets is used to find the bucket for a particular key.

Comment: Thanks, that illuminated things alot. For triggering the rehash, is that when 75-85% of the buckets have some data? Also when you say allocate buckets, what is allocated and how is data stored in a bucket?

Comment: @rocklegend Right, once a certain percentage of the buckets are filled (or more correctly, some ratio of items-to-buckets is exceeded) then the bucket list is grown. Each bucket is a linear list of items. If two items hash to the same bucket, this is called a "collision" and a lookup for either item requires a linear search of that bucket. For example, if there are 16 buckets, then items with the hash 50 and 66 would *both* be stored in bucket 2. A later rehash with more buckets would eliminate this collision. Ideally you want as few collisions as possible.

Comment: So is it typically only one value per bucket, with each bucket a std::vector of collisions? so if I was expecting a lot of datapoints in normal use, I would allocate a large number of buckets initially?

Comment: @rocklegend I think most will use a linked list (`std::list`) instead, since insertion and removal are supposed to be O(1) on a hashtable, and `std::vector` could require reallocation on insert and a cascade of moves on removal. Yes, if you expect a large number of elements, you can use `resize()` or `rehash()` on the hashtable to increase the number of initial buckets.